# iPhone : Error while trying to change any file name or add new file in project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, git, ios4

I am getting following errors while I am trying to change any file name or try to add any new file in my project.

```
   Error : Bad Signature;
   Fatal : index file corrupt
```

What should I do ?

Comment: I have tried that. Even I have also restarted MAC.

Comment: Clear All Targets and delete build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the index with below command,

```
$ rm -f .git/index
```

then restore index to version in the last commit:

```
$ git reset
```

Or you can use lower level (plumbing) 'git read-tree' instead of 'git reset'.
make a backup copy if you want, before removing index

Comment: How did you know it was a git issue if the OP never said anything about using a git repo?